# Taylor Series about the function $\log(x + 1)$

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion, closed-form

I read the following taylor expresion for 
$$\log (x+1)=\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^k}{k}+\frac{(-1)^n x^{n+1} \, _2F_1(1,n+1;n+2;-x)}{n+1}$$
Do you know where it comes from?

Comment: How familiar are you with hypergeometric series?

Comment: Posts of this kind don't match the quality standards for this site. Please edit the question to add more context. Where did you read this? Why is it of interest? What do the parts of the formula mean? What have you tried? You can edit your post to add additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may start with
$$
\begin{align}
\log(1+x)&=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+xt} \, dt 
\\\\&=x\int_0^1 \frac{1-(-1)^{n}(tx)^{n}}{1+xt} \, dt+\int_0^1 \frac{(-1)^{n}x^{n+1}t^n}{1+xt} \, dt
\\\\&=x\int_0^1\sum _{k=1}^n(-xt)^{k-1}\:dt+\int_0^1 \frac{(-1)^{n}x^{n+1}t^n}{1+xt} \, dt
\\\\&=\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^k}{k}+(-1)^{n}x^{n+1}\int_0^1 \frac{t^n}{1+xt} \, dt \tag1
\end{align}
$$ then one may deduce the desired identity from the Euler  [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Integral_formulas) (1748) concerning $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$:
$$
B(b,c-b)\,_2F_1(a,b;c;z) = \int_0^1 t^{b-1} (1-t)^{c-b-1}(1-xt)^{-a} \, dt \qquad \text{Re}(c) > \text{Re}(b) > 0,
$$ with $b=n+1$, $c=n+2$, $a=1$, $z=-x$, which gives
$$
\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(n+2)}\,_2F_1(1,n+1;n+2;-x) = \int_0^1 \frac{t^{n}}{1+xt} \, dt. \tag2
$$ Inserting $(2)$ into $(1)$ yields the sought identity.

Comment: very nice demostration..

Answer (score 0):

Another was is to note that

$\begin{array}\\
(1+x)\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k x^k
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k x^k+\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k x^{k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k x^k+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1} x^{k}\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^n ((-1)^k+(-1)^{k-1}) x^k+ (-1)^{n} x^{n+1}\\
&=1+ (-1)^{n} x^{n+1}\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$\frac1{1+x}
=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k x^k-\frac{(-1)^{n} x^{n+1}}{1+x}
$.

Integrating from $0$ to $t$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(1+t)
&=\int_0^t \frac{dx}{1+x}\\
&=\int_0^t \left(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k x^k-\frac{(-1)^{n} x^{n+1}}{1+x}\right)dx\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \int_0^tx^kdx-(-1)^n\int_0^t\frac{ x^{n+1}}{1+x}dx\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{t^{k+1}}{k+1}-(-1)^n\int_0^t\frac{ x^{n+1}}{1+x}dx\\
\end{array}
$

which gives  the same integral
as before
(after scaling to $0$ to $1$).